# get input from 'try' to 'catch' in java

Tags: java, try-catch

Here's the exercise:

> If the input is a valid grade number, the program should print "OK".
>   Otherwise, the program should print the entered value and "is not a
>   valid grade." and prompt a grade number again. The program should keep
>   asking grade numbers until the user enters a valid grade number.

Example out put:

> Enter grade (0-5): 9 
>   9 is not a valid grade 
>   
>   Enter grade (0-5): two 
>   two is not a valid grade 
>   
>   Enter grade (0-5): 2 
>   OK

I use 'try and catch' with NumberFormatException in while loop. However, I can not print the output like the second one in the example. My output would be like:

> Enter grade (0-5): 9 
>   9 is not a valid grade 
>   
>   Enter grade (0-5): two 
>   9 is not a valid grade 
>   
>   Enter grade (0-5): 2 
>   OK

The new input 'two' is not saved. How can i fix this?

Below is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter grade (0-5): ");
        int grade = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());


        if (0 <= grade && grade <= 5) {
            System.out.print("OK");
        } else {
            while (grade < 0 || grade > 5) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(grade + " is not a valid grade.");
                    System.out.print("\n");
                    System.out.print("Enter grade (0-5): ");
                    grade = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {   
                    System.out.println( " is not a valid grade.");
                    System.out.print("\n");
                    System.out.print("Enter grade (0-5): ");
                    grade = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                    }
            }                   
            System.out.print("OK");
        }

}
```

Comment: If you want to print the input, store it in a separate variable before trying to convert it to an `int`. As a train of throughts: you application would crash if the first input throws a `NumberFormatException` since this is not in a `try-catch`-block

Comment: Call this 'input.nextLine()' before your try block begins and save the result in a String. When you get error in parsing you can use this string in error message. Alternatively nfe.getMessage() may be helpful too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the value of `grade` is `9` and the input is `"two"`, what will happen on this line?:

```
grade = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

The line will throw an exception of course.  But more to the point of the question, this line will *not* assign the string value `"two"` to the *integer* variable `grade`.

Store the input in a *string* instead.  Something like:

```
String gradeInput = input.nextLine();
int grade = Integer.parseInt(gradeInput);
```

If this operation throws an exception, the input was invalid.  If it doesn't throw an exception but `grade` is outside the require range, the input was invalid.  But both of these cases need to be tested separately.

Additionally, note that your *first* input parsing is outside of the try/catch.  So it can fail entirely.  Consider a structure like this instead:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String gradeInput;
int grade = -1;

while (grade < 0 || grade > 5) {
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter grade (0-5): ");
        gradeInput = input.nextLine();
        grade = Integer.parseInt(gradeInput);
        if (grade < 0 || grade > 5) {
            System.out.println(gradeInput + " is not a valid grade.");
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {   
        System.out.println(gradeInput + " is not a valid grade.");
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

I imagine there are a variety of ways you can throw it together and refactor to try to reduce a couple of lines repeated here.  But the point is that you *don't* want to repeat the lines of accepting input and parsing it to an integer, like your current code does.  Because if the exception is thrown in the `catch` or outside the `try/catch` entirely then the system will fail.  The attempt to parse the integer value from the string *needs* to be in the `try` block.

Comment: this covers pretty much everything. You might just want to include the definition and declaration of the variable "input" so the code will be complete as well.